# Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am getting null when using `$sm=$this->getServiceLocator()` as a result `$sm->get("XXXXXXXXXXX")` throwing a Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null.
What i am doing is that, while receiving user data in controller i am calling another controller validatorController inside my requested controller which is signupController and in validatorController i am using `$sm=$this->getServiceLocator()` which gives the above error

**Here is my work**

Error comes when i use `$check=$this->_getUserTable()->isUnique($email);` in ValidatorController.php but not in SignupController.php

**Module.php**

```
<?php
namespace User;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use User\Controller\ValidatorController;
use User\Model\User;
use User\Model\UserTable;

class Module {
    public function getConfig() {
        return include __DIR__."/config/module.config.php";
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
        return array(
            "Zend\loader\StandardAutoloader"=>array(
               "namespaces"=>array(
                   __NAMESPACE__=>__DIR__."/src/".__NAMESPACE__
               )
            )
        );
    }

    public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            "factories"=>array(
                'User\ValidatorController' => function ($sm) {
                    $validatorController = new ValidatorController();
                    return $validatorController;
                },
                "User\Model\UserTable"=>function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway=$sm->get("UserTableGateway");
                    $table=new UserTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                "UserTableGateway"=>function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter=$sm->get("Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter");
                    $resultSetPrototype=new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new User());
                    return new TableGateway("users",$dbAdapter,null,$resultSetPrototype);
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

**module.config.php**

```
<?php

return array(
    "controllers"=>array(
        "invokables"=>array(
            "User\Controller\User"=>"User\Controller\UserController",
            'User\Controller\Signup' => 'User\Controller\SignupController',
            'User\Controller\Validator' => 'User\Controller\ValidatorController'
        )
    ),
    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    "router"=>array(
        "routes"=>array(
            "user"=>array(
                "type"=>"segment",
                "options"=>array(
                    "route" => "/user[/:action][/:id]",
                    "constraints" => array(
                        "id" => "[0-9]+",
                    ),
                    "defaults"=>array(
                        "controller"=>"User\Controller\User"
                    )
                )
            ),
            'signup' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/signup',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'User\Controller\Signup',
                    )
                )
            ),
        )
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(//Add this config
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**SignupController.php**

```
<?php
namespace User\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class SignupController extends AbstractRestfulController{
    private $_userTable;

    public function create($data) {

        /*
         * The above error is not coming here
         * $check=$this->_getUserTable()->isUnique($data['email']);
         *
         * But inside the below controller
         */

        // Calling a validatorContoller
        $validator=$this->getServiceLocator()->get('User\ValidatorController');
        $response=$validator->validateEmail($data['email']);

        return new JsonModel($response);
    }

    public function _getUserTable() {
        if(!$this->_userTable) {
            $sm=$this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->_userTable=$sm->get("User\Model\UserTable");
        }
        return $this->_userTable;
    }
}
```

**ValidatorController.php**

```
<?php
namespace User\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Zend\Validator\EmailAddress;

class ValidatorController extends AbstractRestfulController {
    private $_userTable;

    public function validateEmail($email) {
        $validator = new EmailAddress();
        if($validator->isValid($email)) {

            // check if it is a unique entry in user table

            //  ***(THE SOURCE OF ERROR IS HERE)***
            $check=$this->_getUserTable()->isUnique($email);
            return $check;
        }
    }

    public function _getUserTable() {
        if(!$this->_userTable) {
            $sm=$this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->_userTable=$sm->get("User\Model\UserTable");
        }
        return $this->_userTable;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

Error comes when i use `$check=$this->_getUserTable()->isUnique($email);` in ValidatorController.php but not in SignupController.php

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

`getServiceLocator()` is deprecated in ZendFramework 2. You must inject `_userTable` in your `ValidatorController` from your `Module.php` like this :

```
class Module {
...
public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        "factories"=>array(
            'User\ValidatorController' => function ($sm) {
                $userTable = $sm->get("User\Model\UserTable");
                $validatorController = new ValidatorController();
                $validatorController->setUserTable($userTable);
                return $validatorController;
            },
...
}
```

Then add a `setUserTable()` method in your `ValidController` and modify the `getUserTable()` method :

```
class ValidController {
    public function setUserTable($suerTable) {
        $this->_suerTable = $userTable
    }
    public function _getUserTable() {
        return $this->_userTable;
    }
}
```